# How to perform a FFT using FFTW and SDL_mixer libraries

Tags: c++, fftw, sdl-mixer

I want to write an Audio Visualizer using the SDL_mixer and FFTW libraries. I found many tutorials about how to perform a FFT, and I also performed one by myself, but what data does the FFTW need? And yow do I get that data from my with SDL_mixer loaded audio files?

I had no results yet and no code, but I searched for hours now finding nothing helpful who I, as a "beginner" of C++ could understand.
Something like:
1. Read data from audio file,
2. perform FFT with that data,
3. print results
doesn't help me, since I don't know how to get that data, and perform it in realtime. A code sample or a easy explaination would be nice and really helpful

Comment: To be clear: FFT is a _type of algorithm_. FFTW _is the name of a specific software library_ that provides FFT algorithms. FFT stands for Fast Fourier Transform. FFTW is samply "Fastest Fourier Transform in the West", if I recall correctly. So your question sounds a bit backwards. You should be asking, _"how do I perform a **FFT**"_, and _"what data does **FFTW** need?"_

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yeah, the problem is in youtube videos poeple just put background music, and code without comments. Sample codes on website are the same, there are maybe commetns, but they aren't helpful for the reader. I just copied the code (by tipped it in by myself) and ran it. I should change my question: "What data does FFTW need, and how do I get it with SDL_mixer?"

Comment: @alterigel Yeah, that was a typing error, I think I even wrote it correctly in the title

Comment: @alterigel So, how do I get the data from SDL that FFTW needs?